# Create any PrivateKey instance (RSA or DSA or EC) from PKCS8 encoded data

Tags: java, rsa, ecdsa, java-security, pkcs#8

I have an unencrypted PKCS8 encoded file that represents a Private Key. It can be any of these private key types - RSA, DSA or EC. I viewed these files in an ASN1 decoder (https://lapo.it/asn1js/) and I could see the type (RSA, DSA or EC) in the data.

Is there a way to read the PKC8 private key data into the correct Private Key Java object without specifying the key type in code like this -

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8key);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); // Avoid "RSA" here?
PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(spec);
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying the algorithm in `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")`? Shouldn't this be determined from the `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` since it is available in the PKCS8 data?

Sample unencrypted PKCS8 data and their ASN1 decodings which show the key type -

DSA - [link](https://lapo.it/asn1js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

EC - [link](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#308193020100301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D030107047930770201010420E86CA2FDFBF7680D0D52DBDD45F70D50301AAA8A2776585637AF93F46F96DE1AA00A06082A8648CE3D030107A14403420004EAD0E446F54B2220298FA02F4DCE8FC7FCA87E0B721304752927BCF8AEDECD0E022836343D04BF0DC67BA71094F433B7928B2B325F75B42F3EC7CC3218D0ED2E)

RSA - [link](https://lapo.it/asn1js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

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html it looks like there is a `PrivateKeyInfo` description in the key/object, which contains the algorithm used. Use it to load the correct `KeyFactory` instance.

Comment: So you mean to say that PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded() returns the ASN1 encoded data that contains the PrivateKey algorithm? I couldn't find any class called `PrivateKeyInfo` in the JDK classes to load this data into (i.e., the data returned by `getEncoded()`). That's where I need help. How do I read this private key data and get the algorithm type using generic Java APIs without coding specifically for RSA/DSA/EC?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain the reason for downvote. If the question is not clear, let me know and I will re-phrase. Let's say you stumble across a PEM encoded unencrypted private key file (note that this data contains the PrivateKey algorithm). How would you write code to read this data and get a PrivateKey instance without specifying the Private Key algorithm type in the code? I think this is a valid question.

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo looks promising and it's the first google hit. You can try to adapt it for your code.

Comment: Thanks. That link helps. I was not expecting the use of BouncyCastle library (which I don't use currently), but this should work for me. If you can post the code from the link as an answer, I can accept it as a valid answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You can add an answer and accept it by yourself. I will not provide an answer because I haven't tested it, hence only providing the link (which might get deleted). But since you have tested it and you might have a working code base, you can add the answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved with the help of BouncyCastle APIs -

```
/** Read a PKCS#8 format private key. */
private static PrivateKey readPrivateKey(InputStream input)
throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int size = input.read(buffer);
        byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, size);
        /* Check to see if this is in an EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo structure. */
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
        /*
         * Now it's in a PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo structure. Read its Algorithm
         * OID and use that to construct a KeyFactory.
         */
        ASN1InputStream bIn = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(spec.getEncoded()));
        PrivateKeyInfo pki = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(bIn.readObject());
        String algOid = pki.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm().getAlgorithm().getId();
        return KeyFactory.getInstance(algOid).generatePrivate(spec);
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer! After your snippet I found even a way to simplify a bit more. `PrivateKey privateKey = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC").getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo);` I thought it would be to handy to share it here. In this way the last two lines regarding the algorithmId and KeyFactory can be omitted

Comment: Does this work? As far as I know you can't feed a KeyFactory.getInstance() with a OID but you need to supply the name of the provider such as RSA or EC?

Comment: Ah right the default Java provider does not take OID's but the Bouncy Castle provider does (using `KeyFactory.getInstance(algOid, "BC");`).